# iOS: Do not include Storyboard strings in complied application

Tags: ios, storyboard

I want to know whether it is possible to prevent strings in the storyboard of my application to be included in the complied version of my iOS application.

Example: I have a label in a `UIViewController` in my storyboard. It is linked to the `UIViewController`'s class which sets the label's text. So the text written in the storyboard is useless and therefore I do not want to include it in the complied version of my iOS application.

Comment: Delete the label's text in the storyboard?

Comment: The story board and the associated strings for localization are a strangely disconnected pair...  Delete the localization strings and the actual text in the story board takes over and is used in the UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to the storyboard and click on label and than delete text of the label in storyboard.

So now label will not appear to you in storyboard but it will print text from your UIViewController class.

Comment: Oh yes, I did not think about this easy way. Thank you